# PHP、バブルソートアルゴリズムで昇順に並び替える

Tags: php

PHPで10、25、30、5をアルゴリズム的にバブルソートで5、10,25、30のように昇順で並び替えたいです(ただsortでは×)

画像のコードの添削か、新しいコードの提案をお願いできないでしょうか
よろしくお願いします

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードは画面キャプチャではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。また、現状のコードではどのような問題があるのかも説明があると、回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
function bubble_sort(array $data){
    $n = count($data);
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        for($j = $i+1; $j < $n; $j++){
            if ($data[$i] > $data[$j]) {
                list($data[$i], $data[$j]) = [$data[$j], $data[$i]];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

$data = array(10, 30, 25, 5);
$res = bubble_sort($data);
print_r($res);

// Array
// (
//    [0] => 5
//    [1] => 10
//    [2] => 25
//    [3] => 30
// )
```